# Create table with getdate() function

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to create table that have a `getdate()` function

```
CREATE TABLE Orders 
(OrderId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
 ProductName varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
 OrderDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE() 
);
```

but got an error

> ora-00901 right parenthesis missing

Comment: I was under the impression that `GETDATE()` is a T-SQL/SQL Server specific command - I'm sure Oracle has some function, too, to get the current date, but most likely **NOT** called `GETDATE()`

Comment: I think it is 'date' not 'datetime'

Answer (score 3):

You need to use:

- The `DATE` data type (which contains years through seconds data);
- The current date/time in oracle is retrieved using `SYSDATE`;
- The `DEFAULT` needs to go before the constraint; and
- Although `VARCHAR` works and is currently synonymous with `VARCHAR2`, you probably want to use `VARCHAR2` for a string data type.

Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders 
(
   OrderId     INT          NOT NULL
                            PRIMARY KEY, 
   ProductName VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
   OrderDate   DATE         DEFAULT SYSDATE
                            NOT NULL  
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this instead:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
  OrderId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  ProductName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  OrderDate DATE DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL
  );
```

- Changed DATETIME to DATE
- Changed GETDATE() to sysdate
- Moved the NOT NULL after the DEFAULT

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60ce8a/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Since we do not need to write NOT NULL as it accepts default function.

You can try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders 
(OrderId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
 ProductName varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
 OrderDate datetime DEFAULT GETDATE() 
);
```